# jQuery .each to target only first h4 to add to aria-label

Tags: jquery, each, wai-aria

The following add all the h4 text to the aria-label (thanks Tyler). I want to only add the h4 text relevant to each label.

```
var prodname = $(".checkbox").closest("tr").find("td.product-shortdesc h4:first").text();
        $("td.select .checkbox").attr("aria-label", prodname);
```

Currently adds

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" style="" aria-label="name_1 name_2 name_3">
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML in your question: see the "*[mcve]*" guidelines.

Comment: Got the answer but will address this next tome 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the each method
https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$(".checkbox").each(function(){
  var prodname = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.product-shortdesc h4:first").text();
  $(this).attr("aria-label", prodname);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @partypete25. Works perfectly